Why does Mathematica fail to substitute some terms in an expression but not others?
I have an expression of the form:
$A-\frac{e^{-t/t_1} \; a \; b}{c \; t_1} \; U_1 - \frac{e^{-t/t_2} \; a \; d}{c \; t_2} \; U_2 -\frac{e^{-t/t_2} \; a \; e}{c \; t_2} \; U_2 - \frac{e^{-t/t_3} \; a \; g}{c \; t_3} \; U_3 - \frac{e^{-t/t_7} \; {\bf{Eidx}} \; a \; b \; d}{2 \; c \; h} \; U_7 - \frac{e^{-t/t_7} \; {\bf{Esx}} \; a \; e \; g}{2 \; c \; h} \; U_7 - \frac{e^{-t/t_7} \; {\bf{Eidx}} \; a \; b \; e}{2 \; c \; h} \; U_7 - \frac{e^{-t/t_7} \; a \; b \; j}{c} \; U_7 + \frac{e^{-t/t_7} \; a \; b \; k}{c} \; U_7$
(which I've simplified and truncated for ease of illustration of the problem.)
expr = A - ((E^(-(t/Subscript[t, 1]))) a b )/(c Subscript[t, 1])
 Subscript[U, 1] - (E^(-(t/Subscript[t, 2])) a d)/(
c Subscript[t, 2]) Subscript[U, 2] - (
E^(-(t/Subscript[t, 2])) a e)/(c Subscript[t, 2])
 Subscript[U, 2] - (E^(-(t/Subscript[t, 3])) a g)/(
c Subscript[t, 3]) Subscript[U, 3] - (
E^(-(t/Subscript[t, 7])) Eidx a b d)/(2 c h)
 Subscript[U, 7] - ((E^(-(t/Subscript[t, 7]))) Esx a e g )/(2 c h)
 Subscript[U, 7] - (E^(-(t/Subscript[t, 7])) Eidx a b e)/(2 c h)
 Subscript[U, 7] - (E^(-(t/Subscript[t, 7])) a b j)/
c Subscript[U, 7] + (E^(-(t/Subscript[t, 7])) a b k)/
c Subscript[U, 7];

I have three separate lists of the summed terms in the expression, where each term is sorted according to whether it is multiplied by ${\bf{Esx}}$, ${\bf{Eidx}}$ or appears free of either of those factors. The position of each term in the list reflects the subscript of $U$ that the term is multiplied by, like so:
${\sf{UCoeff}}=\{-\frac{e^{-t/t_1} \; a \; b}{c \; t_1}, -\frac{e^{-t/t_2} \; a \; d}{c \; t_2} - \frac{e^{-t/t_2} \; a \; e}{c \; t_2}, -\frac{e^{-t/t_3} \; a \; g}{c \; t_3}, 0, 0, 0, - \frac{e^{-t/t_7} \; a \; b \; j}{c} + \frac{e^{-t/t_7} \; a \; b \; k}{c}\}$
${\sf{EsxUCoeff}}=\{0,0,0,0,0,0, -\frac{e^{-t/t_7} \; a \; e \; g}{2 \; c \; h}\}$
${\sf{EidxUCoeff}}=\{0,0,0,0,0,0,-\frac{e^{-t/t_7} \; a \; b \; d}{2 \; c \; h} - \frac{e^{-t/t_7} \; a \; b \; e}{2 \; c \; h}\}$.
I want to identify each term in the expression according to the above criteria and substitute it with a dummy variable that labels it accordingly. Thus, for instance, $-\frac{e^{-t/t_7} \; a \; b \; d}{2 \; c \; h} - \frac{e^{-t/t_7} \; a \; b \; e}{2 \; c \; h}$ should be substituted with $\sf{EidxUco_7}$.
For this purpose, I have created separate lists of dummy variables, like so:
${\sf{UCoeffDummy}}=\{ \sf{Uco_1, Uco_2, Uco_3, Uco_4, Uco_5, Uco_6, Uco_7} \}$
${\sf{EsxUCoeffDummy}}=\{ \sf{EsxUco_1, EsxUco_2, EsxUco_3, EsxUco_4, EsxUco_5, EsxUco_6, EsxUco_7} \}$
${\sf{EidxUCoeffDummy}}=\{ \sf{EidxUco_1, EidxUco_2, EidxUco_3, EidxUco_4, EidxUco_5, EidxUco_6, EidxUco_7} \}.$
I use the following code to execute the substitution:
expr = Collect[expr, U]
For[i = 1, i < 8,
 expr = expr /. UCoeff[[i]] -> UCoeffDummy[[i]];
 expr = expr /. EsxUCoeff[[i]] -> EsxUCoeffDummy[[i]];
 expr = expr /. EidxUCoeff[[i]] -> EidxUCoeffDummy[[i]];
 i++]

This unexpectedly substitutes only a few of the terms, as the output I get is:
$A - \frac{e^{-t/t_2} \; a \; d}{c \; t_2} \; U_2 -\frac{e^{-t/t_2} \; a \; e}{c \; t_2} \; U_2 - \frac{e^{-t/t_7} \; {\bf{Eidx}} \; a \; b \; d}{2 \; c \; h} \; U_7 - \frac{e^{-t/t_7} \; {\bf{Eidx}} \; a \; b \; e}{2 \; c \; h} \; U_7 - \frac{e^{-t/t_7} \; a \; b \; j}{c} \; U_7 + \frac{e^{-t/t_7} \; a \; b \; k}{c} \; U_7 + {\sf{\bf{Esx}} \; EsxUco_7} \; U_7 + U_1 {\sf{Uco_1}} + U_3 {\sf{Uco_3}}.$
Why aren't the rest of the terms substituted in and how can I ensure that this happens?
Here below is the code for the generation of the lists.
UCoeff = {-(((E^(-(t/Subscript[t, 1]))) a b )/(
    c Subscript[t, 1])), -((E^(-(t/Subscript[t, 2])) a d)/(
     c Subscript[t, 2])) - (E^(-(t/Subscript[t, 2])) a e)/(
    c Subscript[t, 2]), -((E^(-(t/Subscript[t, 3])) a g)/(
    c Subscript[t, 3])), 0, 0, 
   0, -((E^(-(t/Subscript[t, 7])) a b j)/c) + (
    E^(-(t/Subscript[t, 7])) a b k)/c};
EsxUCoeff = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
   0, -(((E^(-(t/Subscript[t, 7]))) a e g )/(2 c h))};
EidxUCoeff = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
   0, -((E^(-(t/Subscript[t, 7])) a b d)/(2 c h)) - (
    E^(-(t/Subscript[t, 7])) a b e)/(2 c h)};
UCoeffDummy = {Subscript[Uco, 1], Subscript[Uco, 2], Subscript[Uco, 
   3], Subscript[Uco, 4], Subscript[Uco, 5], Subscript[Uco, 6], 
   Subscript[Uco, 7]};
EsxUCoeffDummy = {Subscript[EsxUco, 1], Subscript[EsxUco, 2], 
   Subscript[EsxUco, 3], Subscript[EsxUco, 4], Subscript[EsxUco, 5], 
   Subscript[EsxUco, 6], Subscript[EsxUco, 7]};
EidxUCoeffDummy = {Subscript[EidxUco, 1], Subscript[EidxUco, 2], 
   Subscript[EidxUco, 3], Subscript[EidxUco, 4], Subscript[EidxUco, 
   5], Subscript[EidxUco, 6], Subscript[EidxUco, 7]};



Please edit the question and remove the unnecessary $\LaTeX$ code (or fix the formatting). Keep only the Mathematica code which is relevant for reproducing the issue :) Also, have you tried using ReplaceRepeated? That is, //. instead of /..

Hello, Domen. I have fixed the issue with the $\LaTeX$ (it was not looking like that in edit mode before I posted it!) I tried ReplaceRepeated but that did not work.

UCoeff[[2]] does not literally occur in expr so it is not applied. Maybe if you use Collect to factor the coefficients out from the Us.

I am doing exactly that in this line: expr = Collect[expr, U]. However, that doesn't appear to work either for some reason.
P.S. In my actual program, I've coded the U slightly differently and there Collect does do its job. However, the substitutions are still haphazard, therefore I don't think collecting the terms with respect to U solves the problem.

The explicit inner representation of terms often is not identical with its output form. The most secure form to introduce term abbreviations is:
Find terms of  special form, here eg. products containing an exponential
Eidxterms = 
[expr, Times[Eidx, ___, E^_], \[Infinity]] /. {Eidx :> 1} // 
Flatten // Union;
Esxterms = 
Cases[expr, Times[Esx, ___, E^_], \[Infinity]] /. {Esx :> 1} // 
Flatten // Union;
Uterms = 
Cases[expr, Times[a___?(FreeQ[#, Esx | Eidx] &), E^_], \[Infinity]];

repl= Rule@@@(({#,(Subscript[K, #]&)/@Range[Length[#]]}\[Transpose]&) 
 [Join[Eidxterms,Esxterms, Uterms]])

 
 


expr /. repl
$$A+\text{Eidx} K_1+\text{Eidx} K_2+\text{Esx} K_3+K_4+K_5+K_6+K_7+K_8+K_9$$

Thank you for your response. Your code actually throws up an error in the version of Mathematica I am using (12.0.0.0): 'Syntax::sntxb: Expression cannot begin with "[expr,Times[Eidx,__,E^],[Infinity]]/.{Eidx:>1}".'
In addition, I would like the solution to be more generally applicable to terms not necessarily including an exponential.
